# as3 disable buttonmode on load

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i know this cant be that hard, just not sure why its not firing off.

i have a "home" button that i want to disable on load because the "home" content is loaded by default.

heres my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

// BUTTON FUNCTIONS FOR SP.
// by SOMDOW

/////////////// VARS /////////////// 

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var defUrlReq = new URLRequest("indexCoontentLoad.swf");
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var myLoadedSwf:MovieClip = null;
var swfStage:Stage = this.stage;

/////////////// INITIATE LOADERS /////////////// 

loader.load(defUrlReq);

/////////////// START MAIN HANDLER FUNCTION ///////////////



/////IMPORT DEFAULT SWF /////
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loadedHandler);
function loadedHandler(event:Event){  

    myLoadedSwf = event.target.content;
    addChild(myLoadedSwf);

    trace(myLoadedSwf);

    myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("intro");

}
//----- END IMPORT DEF SWF -----



///// HOME BUTTON TURNED OFF ON LOAD /////  


indexCoontentLoad.addEventListener(Event.INIT, offOnLoad);
function offOnLoad(e:Event):void{
    if(myLoadedSwf.currentFrameLabel == "outro"){
        indexCoontentLoad.mouseEnabled = false;
        trace("lopan");
        indexCoontentLoad.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, offOnLoad);

    }
}

//----- END IMPORT. -----





///// START LISTENERS AND THEIR FUNCTIONS /////

load1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Loaded);
load2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Loaded);
load3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Loaded);
indexCoontentLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Loaded);

//----- END LISTENERS -----



///// test /////


//indexCoontentLoad.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,offOnLoad);

/*function btn4Loaded(e:Event):void { //-- START btn4Loaded
        if (myLoadedSwf.currentLabel == "outro") {
            myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("outro");

            trace("STEP 2 -- swf outro playing");
        }
*/


//----- test end



///// START BTN FUNCTIONS /////

function btn4Loaded(e:Event):void { 
        if (e.target == load1 || e.target == load2 || e.target == load3 || e.target == indexCoontentLoad) {
            myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("outro");

            removeChild(myLoadedSwf);

            urlRequest = new URLRequest(e.target.name+".swf");
            loader.load(urlRequest);
            addChild(myLoadedSwf);
        }
        if(e.target == load1){
            load1.mouseEnabled = false;
            load2.mouseEnabled = true;
            load3.mouseEnabled = true;
            indexCoontentLoad.mouseEnabled = true;

        }
        if(e.target == load2){
            load2.mouseEnabled = false;
            load3.mouseEnabled = true;
            load1.mouseEnabled = true;
            indexCoontentLoad.mouseEnabled = true;

        }
        if(e.target == load3){
            load3.mouseEnabled = false;
            load2.mouseEnabled = true;
            load1.mouseEnabled = true;
            indexCoontentLoad.mouseEnabled = true;
        }
        if(e.target == indexCoontentLoad){
            load3.mouseEnabled = true;
            load2.mouseEnabled = true;
            load1.mouseEnabled = true;
            indexCoontentLoad.mouseEnabled = false;
        }

}

//----- END BTN FUNCTIONS
```

this above doesnt do anything. "indexCoontentLoad" is a button.

i also tried something like:

```
function indexCoontentLoad(e:Event = null){
//code here 
}
```

then calling it later via indexCoontentLoad();

but again nothing.

any help is appreciated. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are adding a INIT Event and removing a ENTER_FRAME Event. There is no logic to that. Maybe there are code you are not providing us.

I would use a Loader to manage the loading and wait for the COMPLETE Event. Then I would activate the button using .

Loader:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

```
private function loadContent() : void
{
    // add listeners and load external SWF
}

private function onLoadContentComplete(event : Event) : void
{
    // remove listeners

    // setup/activate button here
}
```

Comment: Hello there Mattias, thank you for your time, yeah i messed that up, i had that whole function block set for the COMPLETE event and was trying something else b4 i came here. forgot to set the code back to what i had it. But yes i updated my post to reflect my full code. i heavily comment so youll find the code block im trying to implement in the "HOME BUTTON TURNED OFF ON LOAD" part. im ust trying to turn it off on load

Comment: solved it, updated my code. now my problem is, if you click the buttons accordingly, it goes ok but if you click any button too fast, it loads ontop of other external swf. look at what i mean, http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/tst